# How to make Eclipse automatically show selected file in explorer?

Tags: eclipse

In one of my projects, I guess I enabled a setting somewhere that I didn't realize how much I use.

Whenever I click into the main editor, it brings the package explorer to the file automatically and scrolls to it. I can't seem to find this setting anywhere in preferences, does anyone know what it is called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called "Link with Editor", the two-way arrow icon you'll find in the toolbars of various Views.

[image: https://help.eclipse.org/2020-12/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/reference/ref-27.htm?cp=0_4_4_1_4]